# Script works via browser, not via CLI?

Tags: php, heroku

When i access from browser, the script works. When i 'run heroku php script.php' it doesn't give errors but won't fill the .txt

```
$url = fopen ( '<INSERT JSON FEED>', 'r' ); 
$result = fgets ( $url, 5000 );

$parts = explode(',{"title"', $result);
$parts = array_slice($parts, 0, -1);
$result = implode(',{"title"', $parts)."]";
fclose ($url); 

$myfile = fopen("/app/web/CMS-feeds/requestFiles/Elektricien-data.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $result);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with permissions or PHP's configuration in being able to write to files.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information about the error by enabling error reporting. To enable the error reporting you can add these lines to the top of your php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```